# beamer class on MikTex2.9

Tags: beamer, hyperref, installing, miktex

I'm having a hard time getting MikTex ready to produce `\documentclass{beamer}` Documents.

The MikTex-package-manager says that "beamer" is already installed. I de-installed and installed it again, still the example document isn't compiling.

All i can understand by reading the command line is that some hyperref-library stops working.
See here an excerpt of the output:

```
    (C:\Users\altug\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepa
tterns.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\altug\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\xxcolor.sty)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty")

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hdvips.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pdfmark.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty")))
```

Searched the stackexchange, found a thread, stating "you just need to install "hyperref"-lib over "mpm" ". Problem is can't install "hyperref" over mpm, because i neither can click on install nor on un-install, both remain grey. What to try next?

I desperatly need this beamer-class installed due to some work at university.
Thanks for help, if you need additional information let me know!

Comment: 1) Have you tried doing all this with the admin versions of Package Manager if we're talking about a multiple user install? 2) Have you updated all packages with admin and not-admin update?

Comment: It seems that **beamer** is properly installed. Please, show us your document's preamble: that message usually has to do with incompatible packages.

Comment: @doncherry: REGARDING 1): I started the "mpm-admin version" over "Start->MikTex 2.9", then searched for "hyperref" again, it appears to be already installed(since only un-install is "clickable"). REGARDING 2): Tell me how to do an "all-package-upgrade".

Comment: @egreg: What do you exactly mean with "preamble"? The beginning of the "test.tex"-file or the "command line compilation text" when doing "latex test.tex" ?

Comment: Start→All Programs→MiKTeX 2.9→Maintenance (Admin)→Update (Admin); then "next" and "next". Do the same thing with the version without "Admin". The _preamble_ is everything before `\begin{document}` in your .tex file.

Comment: `Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.` is a normal and harmless message. Both beamer and hyperref are obviously installed correctly. Whatever your problem is it is something else.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer: May this part of the "latex-compile-message" be of help? Here: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available (Font) size <5> substituted on input line 6. [1] ... [2] ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd") ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd") [3] [4]
[5] (C:\Users\altug\Desktop\studium\semester3\Seminar\Tex-docs\test.aux) LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences (Font)up to 1.0pt have occurred.) Output written on test.dvi (5 pages, 52996 bytes). Transcript written on test.log.`

Comment: No, that part is irrelevant; what's needed is what precedes `\begin{document}`, as doncherry said.

Comment: @doncherry: Can't update any of the packages listed. The message is: "This package cannot be updated right now. Let the wizard conclude. Then run the wizard again." @egreg: the preamble is: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`

Comment: What is needed is your actual problem. What doesn't work? The log-shows that 5 pages have been created successfully. But you have generated a dvi. Do you want a pdf? Did you actually used pdflatex?

Comment: Problem solved: The beameruserguide says that i need to run the "pdflatex" -command on the "test.tex"-file. I've been trying with "latex" all the time.Now there is at least some output. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Feel free to add this as an answer and accept it, so that this question is "officially answered".

Comment: @doncherry: Due to the reputation restriction it is not possbile for me to answer my own question!

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that ... you'll have to wait another 6 hours: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Originally posted as a comment by the OP user7581)

Problem solved: The beameruserguide says that i need to run the `pdflatex` command on the `test.tex` file. I've been trying with `latex` all the time. Now there is at least some output. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @user7581 would you like to accept the given answer to close this question?